# Catering grade electrolysis of alcohol

Tags: electrolysis, alcohols

Would the electrolysis of alcohol, specifically spirits, result in a potable end product? I'm looking for some novel cocktail ingredients.

Comment: [This one](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16370/electrolysis-of-beer) came up a while ago for beer, but the principles are similar. If the intent is to remove water, it probably won't work and might produce all kinds of weird products that may or may not be safe to consume.